# ¿Cómo puedo escalar una imagen sin perder calidad?

Tags: c#

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que tengan mejor calidad las imágenes que proceso? Intento subir una imagen, escalarla y posteriormente guardarla, sin embargo el resultado me devuelve una imagen con peor calidad de la que subí.

Este es el código que la escala.

```
// Calcular nuevas dimensiones de la imagen.
var ratioX = (double)width / this._input.Width;
var ratioY = (double)height / this._input.Height;
var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

var newWidth = (int)(this._input.Width * ratio);
var newHeight = (int)(this._input.Height * ratio);

var b = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);

using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
{
    b.SetResolution(this._input.HorizontalResolution, this._input.VerticalResolution);
    g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    g.DrawImage(this._input, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
 }
```

Edición:
Es para una aplicación wen en .NET Framework 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrias usar codigo basado en las librerias de GDI que te ayuden en esta tarea

[High quality image resize (C#)](http://programanddesign.com/cs/high-quality-image-resize-c/)

[Resizing an Image without losing any quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87753/resizing-an-image-without-losing-any-quality)

esto permite redimensionar a imagen, por supuesto si aumentas el tamaño puede que se pierda calidad, todo va a depender de la resolucion de la imagen original, pero no deberias tener problemas si reduces las dimensiones

Tambien podrias evaluar librerias

[Simple.ImageResizer](https://github.com/terjetyl/Simple.ImageResizer)

[ImageProcessor](http://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor/imagefactory/resize/)

Esta ultima parece ser muy buena

---

Si el desarrollo es web y quieres aplicar un resize dinamico evalua

[ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/)

basicamente es un handler que permite definir las dimensiones de las imagenes y esto se aplica en runtime sobre la imagen real

Comment: Estoy revisando los primeros dos enlaces, gracias y reviso enseguida los otros.

Comment: ImageProcessor parece que solo funciona con .NET 4.5>, y solo puedo usar .NET 4.0...

Comment: si puede ser, como no mencionaste que framework usabas propuse los que vi con mejor implementacion. No puede actualizar el desarrollo a .net 4.5 ? si usas VS2012 o superior solo lo cambias en las propiedades del proyecto, por supuesto el cliente debe tener ese framework instalado

Comment: Eso me gustaría, pero otra cosa que no mencioné es que es para Web, y el servidor donde se alojará no se le puede cambiar el .NET Framework...

Comment: edite la pregunta agregando una libreria muy buena para aplicar resize en la web

Comment: ¡Genial! Muchas gracias...